# I would like to test a secondhand laptop

Tags: laptop, testdisk, memtest, speedtest

I'm shopping for a secondhand laptop (Alienware). I would like to know what are main things I should test on the machine. What are some tools/applications to do that? I need to find tools that don't take 24 hours to test.

Comment: Depends what to test.. but 2nd hand laptop is usually: 1. Dirty inside (around the fan and exhaust), 2. battery dying or not holding charge, 3. HDD may be dying. You can try to run some software like burn in test and see whether it passes, or how quick it passes.. but yeah, this is too broad, and will be opinion heavy.

Comment: I think it is not important that you know about the quality of Battery, HDD and etc. You will check the laptop configuration and inaccessible components which use secondhand components and the components have not been repaired and changed with low quality of spare parts in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Two things that are actually drastically decreasing in laptop's hardware. The battery, and the hard drive. Get a SMART checking tools ([lots](http://www.passmark.com/products/diskcheckup.htm) [of](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/disk_smart_view.html) them free) to ensure the disk is still in good condition, and use [powercfg](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PowerCfgTheHiddenEnergyAndBatteryToolForWindowsYoureNotUsing.aspx) to generate reports about the battery status.

Memory should last forever, the fans might be clogged (cleanable), and some keys might be broken (don't buy). General physical integrity should be obvious (no funny noise when you open and close it).